# Gearhead & 'teeth-track' to drive rotation of ringed encasement?

Tags: gears, stepper-motor

I am not an engineer, so apologies if this one is a bit of an ill-thought out...

Can anyone show me an example of something like the following scenario:

A small stepping motor driving rotation of a ringed encasement, via a gearhead on the rotation shaft interlocking with a 'teethed track' which is inlayed on the wall of the encasement (I know, see the diagram).

If not, why is this a stupid idea? The stepping motor has to be small to fit in the encasement (for a 'wearable') - are the forces involved here unreasonable?

The ringed encasement is supposed to rotate to a precise position - I imagine that in these situations, rotation would continue after the power to the stepping motor was killed, necessitating some kind of braking mechanism?

I appreciate your help[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qK4Eb.jpg)

Comment: Not really an electrical question, I suppose. But a swing gear on an excavator or a crane is very similar so what your looking for? Not really sure...

Comment: You're right - more of a physics one... I just thought maybe someone would recognise the situation or an alternative more readily on this forum.

Thanks, I'll take a look!

Comment: The general concept is called [rack and pinion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rack_and_pinion), but in your case, you're wrapping the rack into a circle, creating an [internal gear](https://www.google.com/search?hs=bZ2&channel=fs&q=internal+tooth+gear&tbm=isch).

Comment: How much mass is in the rotated object - so you can then consider braking...

Comment: Ive seen aperture rings that work with this principle. Ive built turntables with similar idea.